# PHP catch fatal error and redirect

Tags: php, try-catch, fatal-error

Sometimes I get a fatal error in this line

```
$result = $db->execute($query);

$primary = $result->getRows();
```

**Fatal error: Call to a member function getRows() on a non-object**

I'm searching for a solution to catch this error and redirect to index page.

Rewriting something is complicated, because the system is old.

Comment: Don't try catch this, check if `$result` is an object/not boolean.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error/

Comment: not exactly, if the error can be prevented, it doesn't need to be catched

Comment: What driver is used for $db?

Comment: @DaveChen http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getrows.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$result = $db->execute($query);

if ($result===false) {
    header("Location: errorpage.php");
    exit;
}
$primary = $result->getRows();
```

Comment: +1 for using a guard clause instead of putting all your success logic inside a giant if statement.

Comment: I can't use header because get warning that header already send

Comment: Please make sure that nothing else is echo'd or displayed on the page. I wouldn't recommend, but you could use the ob_*, or echo javascript to redirect.

Comment: The best method is of course NOT having any content before header.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, there shouldn't be an error either way.

**You have to fix your code to correct the error, instead of writing new code to handle it.**

Get the error message out of DB to see the certain problem that caused this error and fix it.

Also

- You cannot catch a fatal error in general.
- **You shouldn't redirect anywhere.** In case of error a '503 HTTP header' have to be returned, along with generic 503 page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that execute() will return FALSE under some circumstances and a boolean is not the result object.

To avoid this error you should always be checking the output of execute() if it was even executed successfully.

For example:

```
$result = $db->execute($query);

if ($result !=== false) {
 $primary = $result->getRows();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to know what $db is, you have not included the code where $db is initialised or informed us as to what this references.

Assuming you are using the PDO library, the PDO object itself has PDO::exec() and the PDOStatement object has PDOStatement::execute().  I therefore assume $db is an instance of PDOStatement and you are calling the execute() method, which returns a boolean, false upon a failure and true upon success - it does not return an object upon success.  If successful, you should then call $db->fetchAll();

```
if (!$db->execute($query)) {
    header("Location: error.php");
    exit;
} 

$rows = $db->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can't catch an error... only exceptions.... luckily with PHP you can set up an error_handler that does throw exceptions. (from comments on php [ErrorException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php) page)

```
class ErrorHandler extends Exception {
    protected $severity;

    public function __construct($message, $code, $severity, $filename, $lineno) {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->code = $code;
        $this->severity = $severity;
        $this->file = $filename;
        $this->line = $lineno;
    }

    public function getSeverity() {
        return $this->severity;
    }
}

function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorHandler($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}

set_error_handler("exception_error_handler", E_ALL);
```

So for your specific problem you would just do:

```
try{
    $result = $db->execute($query);
    $primary = $result->getRows();
} catch (ErrorHandler $e){
    header("Location: /index.php");
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Just saying, your class is not a "handler", maybe you should change its name. There's a built-in exception that does exactly this: http://br.php.net/errorexception

Answer (score -1):

If you get the error message "header already sent" it's because something is already outputted. For instance:

```
echo "hello world;";
header("Location: errorpage.php");
```

or:

```
 <?php // notice the space before <?php 
header("Location: errorpage.php");
?>
```